# Install Lotus Domino on Centos

Tags: linux, installation, centos, lotus-notes

I'm trying to install a trial version of Lotus Domino (from [this official download page](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/it/notesanddominofamily)) on a Centos machine.

I'm following [this instruction page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4217112/Domino9onCentOS6.pdf) to install Lotus Domino. But when I'm trying to launch the server I got those errors:

```
# /opt/ibm/domino/bin/server  -q myhost.net
/opt/ibm/domino/bin/server: line 317: cd: /root: Permission denied
Error - can't open /proc/sys/fs/file-max.
        errno: 13
        Permission denied
Error - can't open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout.
        errno: 13
        Permission denied
Error - can't open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog.
        errno: 13
        Permission denied
Error - can't open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse.
        errno: 13
        Permission denied
Error - can't open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range.
        errno: 13
        Permission denied
```

I don't know how to resolve it.. any ideas?

This is my Centos configuration, just for sake of information:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab102.9 (root@kbuild-rh6-x64) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Dec 19 20:34:40 MSK 2014
# uname -r
2.6.32-042stab102.9
# cat /etc/*elease*
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
cpe:/o:centos:linux:6:GA
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       10G  4.8G  5.3G  48% /
...

# /sbin/sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
error: permission denied on key 'kernel.sysrq'
error: permission denied on key 'kernel.core_uses_pid'
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables" is an unknown key
error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables" is an unknown key
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

Any other information needed?

Comment: Why downvote? Is this question not clear, not well documented, too common or trivial?

Comment: Well, you've got a half dozen `Permission denied` errors, and you're getting a prompt of `$ `, which suggests that you're not running as superuser (root), so, yes, that's pretty trivial. (But I'm not the one who downvoted.)

Comment: You are right, but the result is the same with the root privilege. and all the command prompted with the normal user shell `$` are only command to check the version of the system, available also as a normal user.. I'm editing the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions / ownership issue. The "bindsock" and "tunelrnl" files must be chmod'd to "4555." Additionally, I am not entirely sure it matters, but bindsock should be in the "bin" group, while tunekrnl should be in the "daemon" group.

Make sure to set ownership AND then set file permissions.